# what is wrong with grep bash function

Tags: bash, grep

I have function

```
function contain() {
  if [[ $(echo "$1" | grep "$2" | wc -c) -gt 0 ]]; then
    return 0 
  else
    return 1 
  fi
}
```

when I write instead

```
if [[ $(md5sum -c tool | grep -v "OK$" | wc -c) -gt 0 ]]; then
```

this

```
if contain "$(md5sum -c tool)" "OK$"
```

wants not work

Comment: Your function seems fine.  What is the output of `md5sum -c tool`?  Also, please explain what you mean by "not work" -- does it give wrong result, does it throw an error?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)